# What should I set the “realm” in the “WWW-Authenticate” HTTP header to, for a one-time-password–challenge?

Tags: http, http-headers

As I understand it, a [*realm*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-2.2) is a protection space within which you can authenticate with the same credential(s).

---

The *challenge* my server gives demands a unique **un-reusable** credential that can be used to authenticate only once (“one-time credential”).

```
WWW-Authenticate: reCAPTCHA realm=__________
```

In this case, what do you think the realm should be, a UUID? Or should I not set it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly point out, the realm is supposed to allow logical separation. Setting it to a UUID is actually a pretty good idea. Leaving it unset, OTOH, would mean no separation at all: all credentials in this case were part of the 'no realm' realm.